# How to delete url in git

Tags: git, git-remote

I am pushing data to github. When I push data i am facing problem.I am pushing data using this.

```
git init
touch README.md
git add .
git commit -m "initial commit"
git remote add origin https://github.com/YourAccount/firstPush.git
git push -u origin master
```

Actuall I run  `git remote add origin https://github.com/YourAccount/firstPush.git` this command wrong.
When I again push data with correct path I got error

```
fatal: remote origin already exists.
```

Answer (score 12):

You can follow any of the following 3 methods:

1. Remove the old `origin` and readd the correct one:

   ```
   git remote remove origin
   git remote add origin <correct address>
   ```
2. Update the existing remote links:

   ```
   git remote set-url origin <correct url>
   ```

   you can optionally provide `--push` to the above command.
3. Update the `remote` section of your `.git/config` file:

   ```
   [remote "origin"]
       url = <correct url>
       fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
   [branch "master"]
       remote = origin
       merge = refs/heads/master
   ```

You can also refer to git documentation for the [`git remote`](http://devdocs.io/git/git-remote) commands.

Answer (score 1):

Use this command

```
$ git remote set-url <remote repository url>
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the .gitconfig file in your local computer.
Open it with notepad and delete the urls from there.

The following command will show you where your url is living.

```
git config --list --show-origin
```